# Makefile: "undefined reference to cos"

Tags: c, makefile, clang

I have just started learning about makefile files. I created a program that consists of two functions and wanted to use a makefile to put it all together. This is my file:

```
#Makefile

all: main

main: main.o find_root.o
    clang -o main main.o find_root.o

main.o: main.c
    clang -c -Wall --pedantic -std=c11 main.c -lm

find_root.o: find_root.c
    clang -c -Wall --pedantic -std=c11 find_root.c -lm

clean: rm -f main *.o*
```

However, when I run this, I get an error - "undefined reference to cos". I am using the cosine functions in my program, but I have already linked the library to the compilation of those two files. I thought about adding "-lm" to the first clang option as well. This led to no errors, but it made a warning instead - saying that "-lm linker is unused". What should I change in my file?

Comment: You don't link with libraries when creating the object files, but when you create (and *link*) the executable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Remove all `-lm`s and then change `clang -o main main.o find_root.o` to `clang -lm -o main main.o find_root.o`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm not sure about clang, but for some linker front-ends you would need to put the `-lm` option after the `.o` files like this: `clang -o main main.o find_root.o -lm`.

Comment: There is a mistake in the `clean:` rule in the Makefile. It currently has the command part of the rule where the target dependencies should go. Move the `rm` command onto the next line, indented, to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "-lm" is a linker option but you have only included it in your compilation rule (`main.o: main.c`). You need to include it in your linker rule (`main: main.o find_root.o`).

As it stand the `-lm` option is ignored during compilation and missing during linking.

Answer (score 1):

The linker flags aren't used when compiling, but when linking, so the command for the `main` rule should have `-lm`, rather than the command for the `*.o` files.

Better would be just to set the appropriate variables, and let Make use its built-in rules:

```make
#Makefile

LDLIBS += -lm
CFLAGS += -Wall --pedantic -std=c11
C = clang

all: main

main: main.o find_root.o
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) main *.o *~
```